# Closure questions

Tags: discussion

I have two separate, but related questions regarding the "vote to close" process, and the logic behind it:

1. I'll use a [specific example](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/close/80737) to hopefully make my question clear.

   - I click the `Close` button. A panel asking "Why" is presented with 5 radio-button-style options.
   - I select `Off-topic because...`, which brings up another panel with 3 radio-button-style options.
   - I select `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network` which immediately presents a third panel.
   - However, the only other site available is the RPi meta site! That's not where I think it should go.
   - **How do I make my recommendation for another site?**
2. Same example as above:

   - I return to the panel asking "Why" with 5 radio-button-style options.
   - I select `Off-topic because...`, which brings up another panel with 3 radio-button-style options.
   - I select `Other (add a comment explaining what is wrong)`, and then add my comment to the text box.
   - Unknown to me, and without prompt or warning, my comment is posted to the OP's question.
   - And [in this case](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98250/multiple-rpi-and-multiple-external-5v-power-sources-connecting-all-gnds-ok?noredirect=1#comment161019_98250), the OP has replied to my comment asking me to explain myself.
   - **Is this *by design*, or has something in the closure-voting logic chain gone wrong?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Some thoughts: [fairly recent](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/587/19949) and [rather ancient](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/330/19949). I tend to go with Goldilocks here and close as off-topic more than migrating stuff away - usually with a comment to repost at another stack while observing their guidelines and standards of quality.

2) [Why does a custom off-topic close vote trigger a comment when other reasons don't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186292/284388) I was always thinking that it is by desing and I consider it a help to the OP. In the specific example the OP was afraid to read that ("*Why close and not move it there directly?*") but the current procedure of migrating questions away simply involves the closing here. So it's not like a "move" but more of a "copy and close".

Comment: Re 1): I must apologize first as I didn't find the "fairly recent" Q&A you've referenced. Beyond that, and wrt Goldilocks' comment that "Migration paths for non-mods are limited [to meta]", I wonder why migration is even listed as an option? I assume the answer is because "that's the way it is" :)

Comment: Re 2): Hmmm... apparently that's documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons) - assuming that's still the rule. Again, I wonder why that fact couldn't be noted in the interface, but again I suppose "that's the way it is".

Comment: *"why migration is even listed as an option"* -> Because there is an option, Meta. ;)  I think some of the mechanisms like this aren't super useful here because of how slowly things happen; on busier sites it makes a bit more sense where there really might be 5 users vote to migrate within a short period of time.